# How do I print a Localized Date with full year and zeros before numbers?

Tags: java, jodatime

For my Java application I'm using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to manage dates. Right now I'm getting the following result with my code:

```
11/8/15
```

where 11 is the day, 8 is the month and 15 is the year; I'm am in Spain. What I want my code to print instead is:

```
11/08/2015
```

That is, to print numbers < 10 with a zero and the number, and to display the four digits of the year.

My code is as follows:

```
String localizedDate = DateTimeFormat.shortDate().print(new LocalDate());
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");`

See: [`DateTimeFormatter forPattern(String pattern)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String)):

Example code:

```
public class DateExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String date = fmt.print(new DateTime(2015, 8, 11, 0, 0));
    System.out.print(date);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
11/08/2015
```

Comment: Yes, but what I want to do is to keep printing automatically the date based on the user's locale, simply whatever the date format would be (based on Locale) print the year as a four digit number and the month and the day as a two digit number. What then the solution could be?

Comment: @fergaral if you have a new question, please ask with the [Ask Question button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: It was what I wanted to ask instead. But, as it turns out, it wasn't clear. So I will post a new question

Answer (score 0):

The Joda Time library allows you to provide a [custom formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Custom_Formatters):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
```